# Setting a timeout to an asynchronous call in Gatling

Tags: scala, rest, timeout, load-testing, gatling

I am using Gatling to do some load test to a microservice architecture. I am testing two REST services; a `POST` on service `A` starts execution of an engine, while a `GET` on service `B` *eventually* retrieves the result of such execution.

Using the `asLongAs` construct, I retry to make the `GET` REST call until the result is not ready. However, I do not want to loop forever. I need to set a timeout or a maximum time of tries.

An extract of the code I am using is the following.

```
scenario("my-scenario")
  .feed(feeder)
  .exec(
    http("post-to-A")
      .post("/execution")
      .body(StringBody(
        """{
          | "information": ${INFORMATION}
          |}""".stripMargin
      ))
     .asJSON
     .check(status.is(200))
  )
  .exec(_.set("result", ""))
  .asLongAs(session => session("result").validate[String].get != "") {
    exec(
      http("get-to-B")
        .get("/result")
        .check(status.is(200))
        .check(jsonPath("$.result").saveAs("result"))
    )
  }
```

How can I set a timeout in the above code?

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After googling a little, I found very little documentation and examples around complex scenarios development in Gatling. An excellent post that came to similar conclusions of mine is the following: [Stress testing asynchronous REST service with Gatling](https://jakubstransky.com/2018/03/28/performance-testing-asynchronous-service-gatling/).

Lacking native constructs that does what I want, the best solution we can build is using [`tryMax`](https://gatling.io/docs/2.3/general/scenario/#trymax) and [`asLongAs`](https://gatling.io/docs/2.3/general/scenario/#aslongas) methods together.

The code posted in my question becomes the following.

```
scenario("my-scenario")
  .feed(feeder)
  .exec(
    http("post-to-A")
      .post("/execution")
      .body(StringBody(
        """{
          | "information": ${INFORMATION}
          |}""".stripMargin
      ))
     .asJSON
     .check(status.is(200))
  )
  .exec(_.set("result", ""))
  .tryMax(10) {
    asLongAs(session => session("result").validate[String].get != "") {
      exec(
        http("get-to-B")
          .get("/result")
          .check(status.is(200))
          .check(jsonPath("$.result").saveAs("result"))
      )
    }
  }
```

Gatling will try to call the second REST service 10 times until a call succeeds. Clearly, you the REST service should be designed properly, responding an HTTP status different from 200 until the result will not be reached.

The only drawback is that

> request failed are counted towards failed requests what in our case would drastically falsify results.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `asLongAs` you can use `during` to go through your loop for a specified amount of time (take a look at [Gatling Session API documentation](https://gatling.io/docs/2.3/general/scenario/) for usage).
Also, you might want to check your condition. So far your loop is only executed if the value for `result` is not an empty String, which means that it won't be executed at all.

Comment: Well, I don't think yours it is a feasible solution. Using `during`, I can't add an exit condition from the loop associated with a business condition.